# Android Studio. Unable to load class 'com.google.gson.JsonParseException'

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Whenever I startup Android Studio, I receive an error message that states Unable to load class 'com.google.gson.JsonParseException'. I have tried restarting android Studio, uninstalling and reinstalling it, re-downloading the dependencies, and updating Android Studio.
[screenshot of Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtIU0.png)

Comment: Ok, turns out I was missing one of the gradle files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your using suitable version of Gson in gradle file
`implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:<specific version>'`